# I am getting the latitude and longitude as 0,0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2

When I run the code , it doesn't access my current location and always provides the latitude and longitude as (0,0) . The code was running fine earlier but now I'm not able to get it why it is causing this problem.
 Code :

GooglePlacesActivity.java

```
   public class GooglePlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

            private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyBb5HiuvOM6nwaTvVnLLekh6LRC1c_xI9Y";
            GoogleMap googleMap;
            EditText placeText;
            ArrayList venuesList;
            Location location;
            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;
            private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
                if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                    finish();
                }
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_places);

                placeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placeText);
                Button btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
                SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
                googleMap = fragment.getMap();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

                btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String type = placeText.getText().toString();
                        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);
                        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
                        Log.d("Gsgsdf",googlePlacesUrl.toString());
                        GooglePlacesReadTask googlePlacesReadTask = new GooglePlacesReadTask();
                        Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
                        toPass[0] = googleMap;
                        toPass[1] = googlePlacesUrl.toString();
                        googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);


                    }
                });
            }

            private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
                int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
                if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
```

GooglePlacesReadTask.java

```
        package com.example.hp.mytask;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

    public class GooglePlacesReadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
        String googlePlacesData = null;
        GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {
            try {
                googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
                String googlePlacesUrl = (String) inputObj[1];
                Http http = new Http();
                googlePlacesData = http.read(googlePlacesUrl);
                Log.d("dddd",googlePlacesData.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Google Place Read Task", e.toString());
            }
            return googlePlacesData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            PlacesDisplayTask placesDisplayTask = new PlacesDisplayTask();
            Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
            toPass[0] = googleMap;
            toPass[1] = result;
            placesDisplayTask.execute(toPass);
        }
    }
```

PlacesDisplayTask.java

```
        package com.example.hp.mytask;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;


    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
        GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
            Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

            try {
                googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
                googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
                googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return googlePlacesList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            googleMap.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
                Log.d("wfaefae",googlePlace.toString());
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
                String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Places.java

```
        package com.example.hp.mytask;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Places {

        public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getPlaces(jsonArray);
        }

        private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            int placesCount = jsonArray.length();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
                try {
                    placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                    placesList.add(placeMap);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesList;
        }

        private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson) {
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String placeName = "-NA-";
            String vicinity = "-NA-";
            String latitude = "";
            String longitude = "";
            String reference = "";

            try {
                if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")) {
                    placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");
                }
                if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")) {
                    vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
                }
                latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");
                googlePlaceMap.put("place_name", placeName);
                googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                googlePlaceMap.put("lat", latitude);
                googlePlaceMap.put("lng", longitude);
                googlePlaceMap.put("reference", reference);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return googlePlaceMap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do a google search on issues like this.  Its answered almost daily.  Basically-  getLastLocation frequently doesn't have a location to give, do not rely on it.  Do not assume you have a location until requestLocationUpdates calls the results callback.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's working in MOTO G-2 but not working in any other phone. That's why I came here !!

Comment: Actually read up on the issue. It explains why that function sometimes works. Model actually has nothing to do with it